# Starting a new project with gmapping: groovy or hydro?

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm starting a project that uses the gmapping package in the pioneer p3dx robot, the robot have ubuntu 12.04, ros hydro and ros groovy installed, and I dont know which of these two distro of ros use for my project, because this is my first project using ROS, and I have no clear criteria for choosing between this two distributions.

Then, which of these two distro will you recommend for my project? the gmapping package is the same in both distro?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220576/starting-a-new-project-with-gmapping:-groovy-or-hydro?/) by [JhonRA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25022/jhonra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would go with **hydro** if you have to choose one of them. If not, I would install **Indigo**. A new distro is generally always better, if it supports packages you need.

If you check http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping, you will see that Hydro is still in **continuous integration** while groovy is not.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JhonRA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25022/jhonra/) on 2015-11-18**:
thank you very much. I will use the Hydro distribution.